# Repackaging a dependency as a fat jar

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have two maven projects. One is a library and the other one is an example utilizing this library.

Because my customer is a little old-school he would like to run the example without using maven and requires that the example contains a folder "lib" containing a fat jar file with the lib.

Using maven-assembly-plugin I have been successful in repackaging my lib. as a fat jar but only if it is declared within the lib.'s pom file. But from my POV I would like to have this declaration in the pom file of the example and not the lib. (in order to avoid polluting my lib. with this nonsense).

So my question is: Is it possible to build a fat jar file for a dependency in a maven project? That is, can I use a plugin like maven-assembly-plugin to repackage my lib. as a fat jar from the pom of my example project?

Comment: Add your pom file / assembly descriptors...and the resulting structure you need...

Comment: deploy your fat jar to a local artifactory( a locally hosted server for accessing distributed packages) and add the dependency of this fat jar, along with repo-url in your example project.

Comment: khmarbaise, could you please elaborate? maybe with an example showing what you propose?

Comment: Manmohan_singh, what you are proposing is another solution right? And doesn't really answer my question. Or do I misunderstand?